# Running an invisible form on the foreground

Tags: vb6

I'm wondering how I would be able to run an invisible form in the foreground (meaning it runs wherever the heck you might be in your computer). I've tried playing around with formless applications using modules but unfortunately nothing happens. I've also tried doing

```
Form1.Visible = False
Form1.WindowState = 2 (Maximized)
```

But it WILL NOT run in the foreground (It will if it's focused on) and also the Windows "warning error" sort of sound (the "ehh." sort of sound in monotone) keeps playing when you hit a key. The coding I tried out is this in case you want to know:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer, Shift As Integer)
If KeyAscii <> 0 Then PlaySound App.Path & "\sounds\ding.wav", ByVal 0&, SND_FILENAME Or SND_ASYNC
End Sub
```

And of course using the Windows APIs for playing wav files (winnm.dll or something I believe)

My main question would be (which means THIS is what I want answered) is how I could possibly make it run ANYWHERE on the computer and not make "ehh." monotone sounds. Because That is obviously not what I wanted to achieve.

Oh, and quick update, I've made it play the proper sound (HOORAY!). Just disregard the latter part of the question.

Comment: Why do you want such a form in the first place?

Comment: **it runs wherever the heck you might be in your computer** what do you mean by this?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: Invisible/hidden forms can not have input focus.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us why you want to do this?
What are you trying to accomplish?

Have a look at the following API:

```
'api for keeping form on top
Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
```

For example call it as follows:

```
  'put form always on top
  With Screen
    SetWindowPos Me.hwnd, -1, 0, 0, .Width, .Height, 3
  End With 'screen
```